# Неправильный вывод IMG из MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

В выводе нету картинок, и вот такое в исходном коде твориться. Если удаляешь TITLE, то придирается к WIGHT и т.д...

```
<td>
<img width="30" height="30" title="</td" alt="Ожидает рассмотрения" style="padding-left:8px; padding-top:5px;" src="http://192.168.5.192/img/status/waiting.png">
</td>
```

**Дамп MySQL**

```
CREATE TABLE `status_app` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `statusName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

-- 
-- Дамп данных таблицы `status_app`
--

INSERT INTO `status_app` VALUES (1, 'Ожидает рассмотрения', '<img src="http://192.168.5.192/img/status/waiting.png" width="30" height="30" style="padding-left:8px; padding-top:5px;" alt="Ожидает рассмотрения" title="Ожидает рассмотрения" />');
INSERT INTO `status_app` VALUES (2, 'Выполнено', '<img src="http://192.168.5.192/img/status/completed.png" width="30" height="30" style="padding-left:8px; padding-top:5px;" alt="Выполнено" title="Выполнено" />');
INSERT INTO `status_app` VALUES (3, 'Не выполнено', '<img src="http://192.168.5.192/img/status/rejected.png" width="30" height="30" style="padding-left:8px; padding-top:5px;" alt="Не выполнено" title="Не выполнено" />');
```

**Вывод в php**

```
<?php
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");

define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/connect.php');

//$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `applications` ORDER BY `id`") or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query("
                        SELECT `applications`.*, `selects`.deviceName AS deviceName
                        FROM `applications`

                        LEFT JOIN `selects`
                        ON `selects`.id = `applications`.device

                        LEFT JOIN `status_app`
                        ON `status_app`.id = `applications`.status

                        ORDER BY `applications`.id") or die(mysql_error());

$text = '
<center><table border="1" style="width:100%;" class="table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th style="text-align:center;">№</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Комната</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Ф.И.О</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">IP</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Неисправность</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Характеристика неисправности</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Дата заявки</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Дата выполнения</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Коментарий</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Статус</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;"><input type="checkbox" id="selall" value="1" class="checkbox"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>';

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$text .= '
    <tr></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>'.$row['id'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['room'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['name'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['regIP'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['deviceName'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['defect'].'</td>
            <td>'.date('d.m.Y', $row['created_date']).'</td>
            <td>'.$row['date_completed'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['comment'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['status'].'</td>
            <td><input  type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="" name="ip[]"></td>
        </tr>';

}
$text .= '';
$text = str_replace('1900-01-01','<span style="color:blue">Не выдан</span>',$text);
echo $text;

   //Закрываем соединение
   @mysql_close($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в самом верху написано одно **http://localhost/img/status/waiting.png** ниже **http://192.168.5.192/img/status/rejected.png**

определись с адресами.

```
<td>'.$row['status'].'</td> // правильное поле то?

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$text .= *******; // вопрос зачем после while стоят {} если выполняется всего одно дейтсвие присвоение?
}
```

Ошибка скорее всего в названиях полей, сделай var_dump($row) и выложи сюда, хотя бы одну строку с var_dump()

Comment: С полями всё правильно. На странице добавления заявок, по умолчанию - 1, на странице "статус заявок" подключаем таблицу (дамп сверху), но выводится всё ровно не слово, а номер - 1.

Запрос в "Статус заявок"
 $result = mysql_query("
  SELECT `applications`.*, `selects`.deviceName AS deviceName
  FROM `applications`

  LEFT JOIN `selects`
  ON `applications`.device = `selects`.id

  LEFT JOIN `status_app`
  ON `status_app`.id = `applications`.status

  WHERE `applications`.id = ".(int)$_POST['search_id']."
  ORDER BY `applications`.id") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: >но выводится всё ровно не слово, а номер - 1.

Я честно даже ругаться не хочу!

Прочитай мой ответ еще раз. Сделай **VAR_DUMP()** и станет все на свои места, не нужно повторять того что итак есть в вопросе!

Answer (score 0):

В колонке **name** выводится просто название, для меня

```
Ожидает рассмотрения (просто названия)
```

А вот то, что написали Вы, находится в

```
`statusName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
```